Could not connect to websocket endpoint wss://
Not able to run Apollo Graphql subscription in Production. It is working fine in local env.
Deployed here https://todo-services-production.up.railway.app/graphql
Using apollo graphql with expres.js. Giving error:

Could not connect to websocket endpoint
wss://todo-services-production.up.railway.app/graphql. Please check if
the endpoint url is correct.

Query:
subscription Subscription {
  getTask {
    title
    description
  }
}

mutation Mutation($title: String, $description: String) {
  addTask(title: $title, description: $description) {
        description
        title
      }
    }

Server file:
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';

import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import cors from 'cors';
import { resolvers } from './resolver';
import { typeDefs } from './typeDef';
import DB from './db/DB';

import {
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground,
  } from '@apollo/server-plugin-landing-page-graphql-playground';

interface MyContext {
  token?: String;
}

const app = express();
const db = new DB();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

const plugins = [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({httpServer})];
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==="production"){
    plugins.push(ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground())
}
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
const server = new ApolloServer<MyContext>({
    schema,
    plugins:[...plugins,{
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              await serverCleanup.dispose();
            },
          };
        },
      },]
});
await server.start();

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  cors<cors.CorsRequest>(),
  express.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server, {
    context: async ({ req }) => { 
       return { token: req.headers.token }
    },
  }),
);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    path: '/graphql',
  });

const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer)
app.get('/', (res,req)=> req.send("hello world"));

await new Promise<void>((resolve) => httpServer.listen({ port: +process.env.PORT || 8080 }, resolve));
process.on('SIGTERM, SIGINT', (...args) => {
    console.log(args)
    httpServer.close((err) => {
        console.log('server closed')
        process.exit(err ? 1 : 0)
    });
});
console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/graphql`);

httpServer.on('close', () => {
    db.closeConnection();
});
// if server closed
process.on('SIGTERM', () => httpServer.close());

